# How do i click on the link while using selenium python

Tags: python, html, selenium, web-scraping, automation

I'm new to python and selenium.
This is an HTML snippet of the page im trying to **scrape** a page [this](https://www.hackerrank.com/domains/algorithms)
I want to scrape on the basis of `data-attr1` given in the html snippet.
Please share some code to find this link and click on it.

```
<a class="js-track-click challenge-list-item" data-analytics="ChallengeListChallengeName" data-js-track="Challenge-Title" data-attr1="grading" data-attr3="code" data-attr4="true" data-attr5="true" data-attr7="10" data-attr-10="0.9" data-attr11="false" href="/challenges/grading"><div class="single-item challenges-list-view-v2 first-challenge cursor"><div id="contest-challenges-problem" class="individual-challenge-card-v2 content--list-v2 track_content"><div class="content--list_body"><header class="content--list_header-v2"><div class="challenge-name-details "><div class="pull-left inline-block"><h4 class="challengecard-title">Grading Students<div class="card-details pmT"><span class="difficulty easy detail-item">Easy</span><span class="max-score detail-item">Max Score: 10</span><span class="success-ratio detail-item">Success Rate: 96.59%</span></div></h4></div></div><span class="bookmark-cta"><button class="ui-btn ui-btn-normal ui-btn-plain star-button" tabindex="0" aria-label="Add bookmark"><div class="ui-content align-icon-right"><span class="ui-text"><i class="js-bookmark star-icon ui-icon-star"></i></span></div></button></span><div class="cta-container"><div class="ctas"><div class="challenge-submit-btn"><button class="ui-btn ui-btn-normal primary-cta ui-btn-line-primary" tabindex="0"><div class="ui-content align-icon-right has-icon"><span class="ui-text">Solved</span><i class="ui-icon-check-circle ui-btn-icon"></i></div></button></div></div></div></header></div></div><div class="__react_component_tooltip place-top type-dark " data-id="tooltip"></div></div></a>
```

Comment: don't forget to mark the answer that solves your problem. See this stack overflow help guide.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the page is not loading as fast as expected you can try:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[@data-attr1='grading']"))).click()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can click on the element using the xpath:

```
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@data-attr1='grading']")
element.click();
```

Answer (score 0):

Since there is no `name` `id` or `class` available directly you can use `xpath`.
The element that you are looking for is in `div` with `class` `challenges-list` and you want to click on first link inside it. You can use this `xpath`

```
//a[@data-attr1='grading']
```

And for clicking you can do

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@data-attr1='grading']").click()
```

Comment: the following xpath does not seem to work, i always get the message(x_path not found)

Answer (score 0):

Use double-click with Actionchains because click might not work in Python.

eg.

```
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
# Get the element however you want
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@data-attr1='grading']")
ActionChains(driver).double_click(settings_icon).perform()
```